# No MathJax on meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

Meta doesn't seem to have MathJax enabled ($x=y$). I think it's best enable it to be consistent with the main site.

Answer (score 17):

I have enabled mathjax on the meta site.  Sorry that was a slight oversight on my part.